# Finite Element Modelling of Hyperelastic Material under 2D Plane Strain Conditions

Tags: finite-element, solid-mechanics, computational-mechanics, hyperelastic

I am currently working on writing a MATLAB code for running a finite element simulation of a hyperelastic material in 2D. Since I am building this simulation as a part of a fluid-structure interaction analysis, the 2D assumption is usually carried out using plane strain conditions. I started from [Kim's textbook](https://mae.ufl.edu/nkim/INFEM/) since he included examples written in MATLAB on simulating hyperelasticity but only in 3D, while the 2D assumptions for hyperelasticity were not discussed.

My two questions are:

1. Most of the literature I found on finite element modelling of hyperelasticity in 2D addresses the plane stress conditions. I understand that in real-life 2D plane strain rubber might not be that common, but I wanted to inquire if there is a more fundamental reason behind this popularity of plane stress over plane strain in numerical simulations of hyperelasticity?
2. I am working on condensing the 3D model into the 2D plane strain model. Is there any resources on finite element modelling on hyperelasticity under plane strain conditions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The plane-stress model is physically more meaningful for modelling thin structures. This is the reason for its popularity. It's rare to encounter problems with hyperelastic material models where the plane-strain condition is appropriate.

However, the plane-strain model for hyperelasticity is relatively easier to implement than the plane-stress model. The plane-strain model is nothing but the 3D model with zero-strain in the third direction, and this can be realised by setting $F_{33}=1$ in the deformation gradient. But, the incorporation of the zero-stress condition in the third direction makes the plane-stress model quite complicated for hyperelasticity.

Almost all benchmark 2D examples of hyperelasticity are with the plane-strain model only. Please refer to my [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045782516300950) and references therein for the details. I suggest [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/nonlinear-continuum-mechanics-for-finite-element-analysis/67AD6DBAAB77E755C09E7FB82565DA0B) textbook for comprehensive fundamental details.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, the formulation in your paper is also nicely detailed. So, the plane strain examples in your paper were solved using 2D formulations, correct? I wonder how you handled the non-zero normal stress in the third dimension? It's because of this non-zero stress component that I am unable to correctly condense it to 2D only.

Comment: Yes, that is correct! We don't have to worry about the stress components in the Z direction in the solution phase as we don't have any constraints on stresses. Set $F_{33}=1$, calculate the elasticity tensor and Cauchy stress and retain only the relevant components to compute the element stiffness matrix and residual.

Comment: Thank you very much, I figured it out. The 2nd Piola Kirchhoff component in the third direction being non-zero threw me off.